# What is the difference between the assumptions of the solutions of these second order linear non-homogeneous differential equations?

Tags: calculus

For this second order linear non-homogeneous differential equations,
$$y''-3y'+2y=xe^x$$
symbolab caluculator says that for the non-homogenous part $g(x)=xe^x$, assume a solution of the form $y=a_0x^2e^x+a_1xe^x$.
On the other hand, $$5y''+3y'-y=xe^x$$ symbolab assumes a solution of the form $y=a_0xe^x+a_1e^x$. I don't understand the difference. How should I assume a solution of the form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it by method of Variation of parameters. The General solution of the homogenous part $y''+3y'+2y=0 \Rightarrow y_1=e^x, y_2=e^{2x}$  is
$y(x)=A e^x + B e^{2x}$. Then the solution of in-homogeneous equation  $$Y''(x)-3Y'(x)+2Y(x)=xe^x~~~(1)$$ will be given as 
$$Y(x)=C_1(x) e^{x} + C_2(x) e^{2x}~~~(2)$$ where $$C_1=-\int \frac{x e^{x} e^{2 x}}{W(x)} dx+A, ~~~C_2(x)=\int \frac{xe^{x} e^{x}}{W(x)} dx+B~~~~(3)$$ Where W is Wronskian of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ which is $W=[y_1 y'_2-y_2 y'_1]$ and here it is $e^{3x}$.

Comment: But how should I choose the right assumption of the solution form? First problem's assumption has $y=a_0x^2e^x+a_1xe^x$. This is different form with (2) in your solution

Comment: @hichewiness (1) is homgeneous equation whose solutions linear combination of $y_1=e^x, y_2=e^{2x}$ these two solutions come when you put $y=e^{mx}$ in (1), you get $m=1,2$ Your actual equation is inhomogeneous which is Eq. (2) where $xe^x$ is the inhomogenity.  Such equations are solve by Method of variation of parameters: $C1$ and $C2$ as given by Eq.(3). Get $C1(x) $ and $C2(x)$ put them in (2), for the final solution.